# Are there any guidelines on migrating from C to C++

Tags: c++, c, migration

I would like to know if you have some links to guidelines to migrating from C to C++.

I'm mainly interested in the constructions to check in the C code that could have problems the compiler can not detect? And what are the workarounds?

Note: Please don't answer with things the compiler is able to detect.

Comment: Can you give us some more context?  Why do you want to use C++?

Comment: The only way to think about this properly is to realize they are two different languages. They are not supersets/subsets, C++ is not C with extensions, etc. The right way to do things in C++ is vastly different than the right way to do things in C. The moment you take your C code and declare it C++ code, you've just written awful C++ code, which should be scrapped or refactored.

Comment: @GMan: It's perfectly valid to use C++ as a better C.  Every approach that works in C works equally well in C++.  C code copied into a C++ project is NOT bad C++ code, it may be suboptimal, but it's not any worse than it was as C code.  Just the stricter type checking and prototype requirement is an excellent reason to compile as C++ even if you never use a single C++ feature not found in C.

Comment: C code *is* bad C++ code.  For one thing, it's not exception-safe.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: "Every approach that works in C works equally well in C++." That's simply not true. An common example is allocating with malloc(); you normally don't do it in C++, and if you still do it, you have to cast from void* to e.g. int*. It's not the case in C.

Comment: @Ben: I disagree. For example, exceptions are a superior method of handling errors. Therefore, if your C++ code doesn't use exceptions, it's not as good as code that does. So if you want your C code to work in a C++ compiler, you're either not using exceptions (and therefore not writing good code), or you're using exceptions but now your C code doesn't work properly (because it has no idea what exceptions are).

Comment: I'm with Ben on this one... entirely reasonable, and sometimes the only practical way, to slide a project sideways into C++ like this.  @dan04: it doesn't have to be yet, it doesn't contain any `throw` statements.  @Bastien: the compiler warns you about that, so it's not an issue given the question's concerns.

Comment: @GMan, @dan04, @Bastien, @Kornel: All of you are measuring by the wrong yardstick.  First of all, this is obviously an embedded system, so exceptions are probably totally unacceptable, period.  Secondly, even assuming a desktop environment where the additional space requirements and latency of exception handling are not problematic, moving from C to C++ without exceptions is still an improvement.  Ok, somewhat writing in that style shouldn't be calling themselves a C++ expert in any interview, but that doesn't mean that the common subset plus a few limited C++ features is worse than C.

Comment: @Bastien: Sure, you're going to need a cast to convert from `void*` to `int*`.  It's a *narrowing conversion*.  That C allows any narrowing pointer conversions without a cast is a serious type safety bug, and that it special-cases `void*` is inconsistent.  Of course C doesn't even try to be type safe, so it's not really a surprise.  That's why compiling the same old C codebase under a C++ compiler is already an improvement, because now the compiler is helping ensure type safety, and typesafe software is more maintainable and usually has fewer bugs.

Comment: @dan No need of exception-safe code when there are no exception ;-)

Comment: @Carl I want to use templates.

Comment: @Tony: The key word is "yet".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to investigate this is just to read through some lists of incompatibilities between C and C++, and see which ones produce run-time issues rather than compilation issues.  Such lists are plentiful, good starting places might be:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B
- http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. This is really a good starting point. I know I should think more often in wikipedia.

Comment: @Vincente: you're welcome.  Sorry it still leaves you quite a bit of investigation to do.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean learning C++ assuming knowing C? Or do you mean translating a C project to C++? If the latter, and if the project is of any significance size, I'd say don't do it. If the project has any momentum then it's suicide; it's a waste of time, effort, motivation and good spirit.

Comment: introducing a few c++ only constructs doesn't hurt much (e.g. use STL for some newer function). just don't try to convert every bit of old code into c++.

Comment: @J-16 Am I missing something? The potential mixing of new/malloc/delete/free sounds like major trouble to me.

Comment: @ J-16 SDiZ: I would even be weary of that. There are a couple of gotchas. Like C++ calling C calling C++ now throwing an exception. Exceptions can not cross over the C boundary here (probably resulting in application termination).

Comment: I mean migrating a C project from C to C++. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Martin: Actually, they can. It's still a bad idea.

Comment: @stefan, keep every thing c++ contained (in a source file, or even in a function), just don't pass it around.

Comment: @Martin, you don't have to use expection

Comment: As with Kornel's "answer", this is also a comment/opinion and not even at attempt to address the question asked.

Comment: @J-16SDiZ: Then the code is poor, because in C++ exceptions are the *better* way of handling errors. You must either admit the code is entirely bad (but works) or is not entirely bad (but doesn't necessarily work).

Comment: @Tony not it's not a comment, and yes of course it's an opinion. Anything I say that isn't mathematical in nature or a statement I logically derived from another statement is my opinion. And yes it does answer the question. If one asks me how to shoot him(her)self in the foot I advice against it, not explain how to go about it.

Comment: @Conrad Meyer: Can what?

Comment: @Martin: Throw exceptions through C code.

Comment: @Conrad Meyer: C does not have an ABI that supports exceptions (The C ABI is well defined unlike the C++ ABI). Thus exceptions can not propagate across a C (ABI) interface (unless it was compiled with a C++ compiler).

Comment: @Martin: Whether the standard supports it or not, compilers (such as GCC) support this.

Comment: @Conrad Meyer: Yes. But the question is not about GCC (or other non compliant compilers) it's about C++/C.  If you spend enough time here you will see that the good answer actually quote the standard as the definitive reference.

Comment: @Martin: There is no "C ABI".  ABIs are, by nature, platform-specific.  And most of the major platforms do specify that the behavior of C++ exceptions in the presence of C code is the same as the behavior of `longjmp`.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Yes I was simplifying. But there are no guarantees that it will work (and not all of us work on major platforms or have the luxury of knowing that the code will not be ported to a platform that will not support this behavior). Would you not say that the C ABI are hardware specific (To me the term platform is the combination of hardware and OS (and potentially compiler)).

Comment: @Martin: C ABI is definitely OS specific in addition to CPU architecture.  E.g. Windows and Linux use different ABIs for C code on x86.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: So platform is the correct term them.

Answer (score 2):

The first two editions of Effective C++ focuses on C programmers coming to C++ running into a lot of pitfalls. I'd say go for Edition 2 of Effective C++ (its basically a rework of first edition).

Maybe my answer is invalid as there actually are a Effective C++ flag for GCC. Also with modern warnings for strict aliasing etc etc you are pretty close to perfect C++ if you get everything to compile with really all warnings enabled.

Answer (score 2):

*You must unlearn what you have learned.*

And more seriously -- the biggest mistake of teaching C++ is teaching it as a superset of C. C and C++ are two different languages with different approaches to solving problems. The syntax may be very similar, but the approach differs. And while most valid C programs are valid C++, this is just a side effect of building C++ on top of C.

Recompiling a C project with a C++ compiler doesn't make the project C++.

Comment: This is a comment/opinion, not an answer to the question posed.  We've no reason to assume Vincente isn't already a good C++ programmer or has to unlearn anything; he's simply asking if there's specific parts of the program that he should search out and verify/correct to get the program running reliably when compiled with the C++ compiler.

Comment: @Tony Thanks for clarifying. You have resumed exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the things that you already know, I suppose, `new`/`delete` versus `malloc`/`free` etc. there is one important danger, namely C style casts. If your code has a lot of these (usually this is bad C code, then) they are difficult to find because of the syntax. But you should convert them all to the correct C++ style casts.

And then there are subtle things that the two just interpret differently, that are difficult to find and may bite you any time from one week to 10 years after you made such a transition.

Identifiers are such a thing. Try to find out if in C++ `stat` means the function or `struct stat`. Where in this example this isn't too bad, since probably the compiler will tell you. But there may be others hidden. `sizeof` expressions are a particular pitfall here, since they can be applied to an expression or to a type.

`sizeof` in general are something that you should check systematically. E.g `sizeof('a')` in C is the same as `sizeof(int)` and in C++ `sizeof(char)` (so `1`). The same holds for `enum` constants versus `enum` variables.